# Unchecked call to 'add(E)' as a member of raw type 'java.util.ArrayList'

Tags: java

im trying to finish my school task and i am bothered in this warning im just new in programming and im seeking for advice here

```
public class Graphs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList> adj = new ArrayList<>();
        char[] vertices;
        vertices = new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'};

        int num = 7;

        adj.add(new ArrayList<>());
        adj.add(new ArrayList<>());
        adj.add(new ArrayList<>());
        adj.add(new ArrayList<>());
        adj.add(new ArrayList<>());
        adj.add(new ArrayList<>());
        adj.add(new ArrayList<>());


        adj.get(0).add('b');
        adj.get(1).add('c');
        adj.get(2).add('d');
        adj.get(2).add('e');
        adj.get(3).add('c');
        adj.get(3).add('e');
        adj.get(3).add('f');
        adj.get(3).add('g');
        adj.get(4).add('c');
        adj.get(4).add('d');
        adj.get(4).add('f');
        adj.get(5).add('d');
        adj.get(5).add('e');
        adj.get(6).add('d');

        int c;
        int x;
        x = 0;
        c = 0;
        while (x < num) {
            System.out.println(vertices[c] + ":is connected to " + adj.get(x));

            x++;
            c++;
        }
    }
}
```

Unchecked call to 'add(E)' as a member of raw type 'java.util.ArrayList'

Comment: You can use a Array list<Character[]> instead where every element is an array itself

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `adj` is of type list of list.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> adj = new ArrayList<>();
```

But the inner list type parameter is not specified. Defining it as below would fix the warning.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> adj = new ArrayList<>();
```